# Docker won't allow change template files in django web app

Tags: django, docker

I have a Django app running in Docker, and while I can change .py files, for some reason (I am assuming Docker is blocking write access) I can't save changes to templates files.
Is there a way around it without spinning down the container?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: gunicorn -w 3 myapp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --reload
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app
      - ./static/:/home/app/web/static
      - ./media/:/home/app/web/media
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    restart: unless-stopped
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./static/:/home/app/web/static
      - ./media/:/home/app/web/media
    ports:
      - 7000:80
    depends_on:
      - web
```

Dockerfile

```
###########
# BUILDER #
###########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine as builder

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2 dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY . .
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --no-deps --wheel-dir /usr/src/app/wheels -r requirements.txt

#########
# FINAL #
#########

# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine

# create directory for the app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/app

# create the app user
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S app -G app
    
# create the appropriate directories
ENV HOME=/home/app
ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/static
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/media
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add libpq
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R app:app $APP_HOME

# change to the app user
USER app
```

Docker is deployed on synology NAS in a shared folder.

Comment: Restarting the application on a change is pretty normal; what's wrong with re-running `docker-compose up -d --build`?

Answer (score 1):

First, you should probably clean up your docker file. You're setting workdir and copying twice, and your first system level pip build is based off a directory you're abandoning. If you're going to set up permissioned users and appropriate directories this should be including a virtualenv and not installing to the image's python build, let alone doing it twice.

Because this hasn't been cleaned up your docker-compose.yml doesn't actually bind to your working directory. It's binding to the old working directory when you specify the volume

```
 - ./app/:/usr/src/app
```

Your app however is instead working off of /home/app/web as specified in the DockerFile, and since it isn't bound to any volume none of your template changes are being reflected. It's actually somewhat perplexing that any changes are being ported over at all.

Comment: Can you recommend a good tutorial on how to write compose file for a Django app? I am new to Docker and was following one that comes high in the search. I don't fully understand this two stage approach.

Comment: I found the article in question, as it's the top search result.  The 2 stage portion is about making the docker smaller for production use. That portion also doesn't bind the source code directory in the docker-compose.yml for production, which is correct in a production image since we don't want to edit source code with it. I think what happened was you jumped to the production stuff and tried to use it as a development environment. You probably want different docker-compose.yml files for dev/prod and possibly even different Dockerfiles.